# old scify novel similar to "miss peregrine"?

Tags: story-identification

Just watched the "Miss Peregrine home for peculiar children" and vaguely remember that I read a sci-fi novel many years ago with a similar setup - a boy finds a group of children with special abilities (lead by a man whose talent is to "glue" the group).

There was a child who can teleport himself (but not his clothes :)) so he teleports himself to a store at night to get some food for the group.

There was a girl who can move other things (e.g. in the first night the the protagonist went outside to pee and afterwards they told him he should not - the girl can just empty his bladder just by her mind. Etc...

I remember the boy ends-up the new "leader" of the group because the old "leader" steps-down and he tells the boy that he also has the talent of "gluing" the group together.

Could you help to identify?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE, take a look at the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get an idea of questions and answers. If there's anymore information you can give about the story, like when you read it? Where you may have read it? What language? the cover of the title etc. to help us find it a bit better, just [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/149049/edit) your post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[More Than Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_Than_Human)* by Theodore Sturgeon. In the original group, there are actually twin teleporters, a boy and a girl; another girl who is telekinetic; and a man who can compel people to do things.

Comment: You're probably right, but if you can add some quotes from the book to back up your answer it would be helpful.

Comment: @nebogipfel Thanks - this is the one! That's amazing how quick you identified it.